# Запятая в предложении перед "как"

Tags: пунктуация

«...продвижение региона как бренда». Верно без запятой?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, верно. Имеется в виду продвижение региона  в качестве бренда. Сейчас эта тема активно разрабатывается, каждый регион имеет своё лицо и свою ценность в государстве.